# Rezults - App build in "Waiting for review" for more than 3 days

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have my app build on TestFlight for the very first time and ever since it has been in "Waiting for review" for **more than 3 days** at the time of writing. I'm not so concerned about the time because I found some bugs in that build and I already fixed those now.

Picture that describes this:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwHVo.jpg)

Now I want to add **another build** - changed and better from the previous one and I'm not sure if I should remove the first one and add another or wait for them to review the app or just add another build and I would have 2 builds.I wanted to get answers from experienced programmers.

Comment: if it's been 3 days and still not approved, I would say that something went wrong on the TestFlight side. It's totally okay to remove that specific version and add a new one with your fixes. You can upload as many version as you want and let them sit there, that's also fine. I would say that there is no need to wait for Apple to approve your previous version since you have something better than before!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me. I heard that If you delete the build and add new on the new one you would have to wait for long time and that's why I was concerned.

Comment: Within the past week Apple has had an outage related to TestFlight reviews (https://developer.apple.com/system-status/).  I'm experiencing something similar (stuck in Waiting for Review for several days) and it may be related to the recent outage.  I have removed my build and resubmitted but the build is still stuck (even while the regular, non-TestFlight build was approved during the time that the TestFlight build was stuck Waiting for Review).

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue this week. We've tried expiring and adding a new build as well. Still stuck.

Comment: Just to update you my app build did get accepted after 3 days and a few hours and after that I uploaded another one which took around 2 days to be approved by Apple.